# constructing Json Table with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, xcode

I'm new at JavaScript, I have a little issue with coding, I have a table `data1[]` which looks like this :

```
data1[]
data1[0]={

    "Houses": [{
        "id": "house1",
        "name": "Homer's house",
        "rooms": [{
            "id": "room1",
            "name": "Chris's room",
            "facilities": [{
                    "id": "chair1",
                    "name ": "chair of leather"

                }
            ]
        }]
}



}




data1[1]={

    "Houses": [{
        "id": "house1",
        "name": "Homer's house",
        "rooms": [{
            "id": "room1",
            "name": "Chris's room",
            "facilities": [{
                    "id": "bed",
                    "name": "king size bed"

                }
            ]
        }]
}



data1[2]={
"Houses": [{
        "id": "house2",
        "name":"Megan's house",
        "rooms": [{
            "id": "room1",
            "name": "Kelly's room",
                "filters": [{ 
                    "id": "sofa", 
                    "name": "corner Sofa"

                    }
                ]
                }]
}]}
```

And I want to construct a Json like this :

```
JsonArray : {
    "Houses": [{
        "id": "house1",
        "name": "Homer's house",
        "rooms": [{
            "id": "room1",
            "name": "Chris's room",
            "facilities": [{
                    "id": "chair1",
                    "name ": "chair of leather"

                },
                {
                    "id": "bed",
                    "name": "king size bed"

                }
            ]
        }]
},{
        "id": "haouse2",
        "name":"Megan's house",
        "rooms": [{
            "id": "room1",
            "name": "Kelly's room",
                "filters": [{ 
                    "id": "sofa", 
                    "name": "corner Sofa"

                    }
                ]
                }]
    }]
}
```

Do you guys have a not complicated and mostly optimized way to do this with JavaScript !!
THANKS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use `Array.map` to iterate and get values from data1 to get data.

```
var data = {JSONArray : {Houses : data1.map(function(ele){
return ele.Houses[0]
})}}
console.log(data);
```

Comment: it's sounds like a good way to resolve my issue, but i don't understand how i could call ele.Houses[0] . could you explain more plese !!!!!!

Comment: in this case ele.Houses[0] actually refers to data1['anyIndex'].Houses[0].

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is only way to go just using objects, you can break this complex json nodes in objects and insert one inside another, but it depends in how you gonna use this data...

**Using FormData**

```
var myForm = document.getElementById('myForm');
formData = new FormData(myForm);
formData.append('username', 'Chris');

<form id="myForm" name="myForm">
  <div>
    <label for="username">Enter name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username">
  </div>
<input type="submit" value="Submit!">
</form>
```

**Creating Raw Json**

Like you did in you example

**Creating each objects**

```
room.id = "room1"
room.name = "Chris's room"

house = {}
house.id = "house1"
house.name" = "Homer's house"
rooms = [room]
```

But this depends in how you gonna work with this, you creating this at backend(NODEJS)? at frontend? you can make it more "pretty" and "readeble" but you will have to write it anyways, can do more "easy"

Comment: All my answer was about frontend bro, you dont need NodeJS to do that, you are manipulating the JSON with pure Javascript in client side